# VLC vlcControl disconnected state

Tags: c#, libvlc

I am using the vlcControl in my C# application to stream an rtsp. I run the control by this code:

```
Private Sub MyControl_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    VlcControl1.Video.AspectRatio = "5:4"
    Dim options = New String() {"--zoom=.75"}
    Dim urlString = $"rtsp://{CurrentOfflineSetting.camuserName}:{CurrentOfflineSetting.camPassword}@{CurrentOfflineSetting.CameraIP}:{CurrentOfflineSetting.CameraPort}/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=1&unicast=true&proto=Onvif"
    Dim url = New Uri(urlString)
    VlcControl1.Play(url, options)
End Sub
```

It plays fine. And if there's an error, I handle it like by reconnecting again like so:

```
Private Sub VlcControl1_EncounteredError(sender As Object, e As VlcMediaPlayerEncounteredErrorEventArgs) Handles VlcControl1.EncounteredError
    Dim options = New String() {"--zoom=.75"}
    Dim urlString = $"rtsp://{CurrentOfflineSetting.camuserName}:{CurrentOfflineSetting.camPassword}@{CurrentOfflineSetting.CameraIP}:{CurrentOfflineSetting.CameraPort}/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=1&unicast=true&proto=Onvif"
    Dim url = New Uri(urlString)
    VlcControl1.Play(url, options)
End Sub
```

My question is; what about if the connection to the camera is disconnected or interrupted? How do I know if it is disconnected and it is not streaming any more? There are times that the stream stops(looks like a pause). As soon as this happens, I can just reconnect but the thing is, I do not know if the streaming stops since it does not raise any error but just stops.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what wrapper you're using, but just like the `EncounteredError` event, you should have a `Stopped` event as well.